# How to make a surface of revolution in manim

Tags: python, math, manim

```
from manim import *


class Solids(ThreeDScene):
    def construct(self):

        x_min, x_max, x_step = 0, 5, 1
        y_min, y_max, y_step = -5, 5, 1
        z_max, z_min, z_step = -5, 5, 1
        axes = ThreeDAxes(
            x_range=[x_min, x_max + x_step, x_step],
            y_range=[y_min, y_max + y_step, y_step],
            z_range=[z_min, z_max + z_step, z_step],)

        function = axes.plot(lambda x: np.sqrt(
            x), color=YELLOW, x_range=[0, 5])
        area = axes.get_area(function, x_range=[0, 5], color=BLUE)

        rec = axes.get_riemann_rectangles(function, dx=0.2, x_range=[
                                          1, 1.2], input_sample_type="left", stroke_width=0.5, fill_opacity=0.75, color=BLUE)
        rec_label = Text("dx", font_size=20)
        rec_label.next_to(rec, DOWN, buff=0,)

        group = VGroup(function, area, rec)
        # parametric surface of sqrt of x but in 3d roatetd about x axis

        paraboloid = Surface(
            lambda u, v: np.array([
                np.cos(v)*u,
                np.sin(v)*u,
                u**2
            ]),
        )

        self.play(FadeIn(axes))
        self.wait(2)
        self.play(FadeIn(function))
        self.play(FadeIn(rec))
        self.play(Write(rec_label))
        self.play(FadeIn(area))
        self.wait(2)
        self.begin_ambient_camera_rotation()
        self.set_camera_orientation(phi=75 * DEGREES, theta=-30 * DEGREES)
        self.play(Rotating(group, axis=RIGHT, radians=2*PI,
                  about_point=ORIGIN), run_time=5, rate_func=linear)
        self.wait(2)
        self.play(FadeIn(paraboloid))
        self.wait(2)
```

I want to make a parabolid that forms when I revolved $\sqrt{x}$ around the x axis, I could not find the formula of the 3d surface so instead I think a better approach would be to generate a copy of the function for all curves when is rotating such that a surface is formed, how can I achieva that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know **manim** but changing your code to the following one should generate a surface of revolution of `f` (`sqrt` for you) around the z-axis:

```py
paraboloid = Surface(
    lambda u, v: np.array([
        np.cos(2*pi*u) * v,
        np.sin(2*pi*u) * v,
        f(v)
    ])
)
```

For the x-axis I would try:

```py
paraboloid = Surface(
    lambda u, v: np.array([
        f(v),
        np.cos(2*pi*u) * v,
        np.sin(2*pi*u) * v
    ])
)
```

or maybe exchange the `cos` and the `sin`.

Here `u` goes from 0 to 1.